# check element if a member of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, membership

i want to do a iterative function to compute if an element el is a member of a list and returns an 
atom.

;;; this is the list
     (setf lst '(a b c d e 1 2 3 4 5))

;;;this is the function to check whether it is a member of the list.

```
(defun checklist (a lst)
           (if (member a alist)
               a))
```

when i put the input -> (checklist 1 lst) , it return the number ... but when i input alphabets, it return me error. .. anyone can help me state out what is the problem ?? thanks in advance .

================================================================================

when i input --> (question5 a lst)

it give me error like this .

CG-USER(7): (question5 a lst)
Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `A'.
[condition type: UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Comment: just show us how the error happens.

Comment: i have put the error on above ..

Comment: Eric: `a` is a variable. You need to quote it so it stays a symbol and doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: thanks .. i know where i did the wrong things .. thanks ya ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that homework?

If yes:

I don't think `member` is useful for you. If you want to do an iterative solution, then you would use something like `DO` or `DOLIST`.

If no:

Common Lisp has a function which finds elements in sequence (list, vector, string, ...): `FIND`.

**Added**: use `(question5 'a lst)`

Also note that your definition has an unfortunate part:

```
(checklist nil '(a b c))

(checklist nil '(a b c nil))
```

both would return `NIL`.

Btw., the Lisp introduction book from Touretzky is free for download:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/
The book provides a nice introduction into the basics of Lisp programming.

Comment: ya it is a homework .. me and my friends confused it for a long time so ask at there ..  if wan to implement do or dolist, how to implement it ?? i havent learnt that yet ..